# Handling keys happens even when textarea is focused

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, keyboard-events

I have a canvas app where I handle `window`'s `keyup` and other events. This works fine. However, now I've created a popup div with a textarea in it, and I don't want my `keyup` handling to be active when the textarea is focused (or when the popup is visible).

I could set a bool `isPopupVisible` and check for that in my `keyup` handling, but it strikes me that much more elegant would be to just use the standard focus management of HTML. So I tried handling the canvas's `keyup` event rather than the window's, but now the problem is that the canvas never receives focus (not even if I click on it) so it doesn't receive any key events. Apparently most HTML elements can't receive focus.

What would be a good way to resolve this?

**Edit**: It now occurs to me that what I want is in effect a modal dialog box, which HTML doesn't natively support. To support this modality, it's normal to implement it manually with a bool as I initially planned. Standard HTML focus doesn't provide for that, even if I could get the canvas to receive focus. Because the user can switch focus back to the canvas by clicking on it even when the popup is still visible (undesirable).

So I guess I withdraw my question.

Comment: focus the textare one popup is visible.
document.getElementById('textArea').focus();

Comment: Have you tried putting a tabindex on the canvas to try to force it to be focusable?

Comment: @user2181397: Sure, I do that, but the problem is that even when the popup is not open, the canvas doesn't receive any key events.

Comment: put some code. That will be helpful